# Parallelize pseudo inverse of a matrix using Lapacke

Tags: matrix, parallel-computing, lapack, blas

I am currently using the protocol described in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599950/computation-of-pseidoinverse-with-svd-in-c-using-blas-and-lapacke to compute the pseudo inverse of a matrix.
Clearly when dealing with large matrices (e.g. 10000 x 10000) the process is extremely expensive and the run becomes quite long.
Is it somehow possible to parallelize this process?

Edit: The purpose of the program is to solve a system of equation

$$ A x = y $$

where $A$ is semi-positive definite (i.e. it can be singular). In order to do this I compute the pseudo inverse $A^{-1}$ and compute $x = A^{-1}y$.
I am currently using OpenBlas.

Comment: 100x100 is very small - not large at all, it should just take a tiny fraction of second and is not worth parallelising. How are you currently trying to do this? If I modify the code in the answer to the question you link to to n = 100 and adjust the set up of `a` it takes less than 0.1 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the typo, I was considering 10000x10000.

Comment: 10000 by 10000 is still fairly small.  Computing the pseudoinverse takes less than 2 minutes on my desktop machine.

Comment: For my purpose I need to repeat the inversion almost 5000 times, therefore reducing it e.g. from 2 minutes to 1 minute would be a great improvement.

Comment: Are the "inversions" related in some way? Or are they all independent? Are the matrices dense or sparse? Are they symmetric? Do you have access to a cluster? If not what hardware do you want to use? Could you use a GPU?

Comment: Do you need an SVD based pseudoinverse for a badly conditioned matrix, or Is the matrix well enough conditioned that you can use the normal equations approach?  Do you actually need the pseudoinverse or just the action of the pseudoinverse on one vector (or a small number of vectors)?

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify some aspects. Hope it can help!

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help very much. Are the A matrices related in any way? Can you simply generate one matrix from the "previous" one? If so how? If not are all all the pseudoinversions independent of one another so we can do may of them at once?

Comment: They are not related and one cannot compute many of them simultaneously. 
The solution of the equation $x$ is an update to a starting vector, the "new" version of $A$ is subsequently obtained by the incremented vector in a non-analytical way (you have to average some quantities, so there is no straightforward way to obtain the "new" $A$ from the previous one)

Comment: Do you need a mininum norm least squares solution to $Ax=y$, or will any least squares solution to $\min \| Ax-y \|$ be satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

LAPACK, and consequently LAPACKE are technically just interfaces. There are several implementations, some of which are already parallel. OpenBLAS and MKL should scale quite well on multicore machines.You should check which version you link with (I would personally recommend MKL, but OpenBLAS is also fine).

You should also check whether all these operations are really necessary. For example, if the matrix $A$ stays the same each time, you can skip the calculation of the pseudoinverse and only apply it to different vectors.

Calculating the pseudoinverse is also a relatively expensive operation. Do you really need to calculate it? If all you need it for is solving a linear system, then you might save a significant amount of compute time with a QR factorization.